# Aligning two <td> horizontally without 'inline' property

Tags: html, css, mailchimp, newsletter

I have read in detail several 'horizontal aligning' SO posts, but this example deviates in a few ways. Here's the example of what I am trying to achieve:
[Newsletter's header as title and newsletter description in two tables](http://us6.campaign-archive2.com/?u=b98e2de85f03865f1d38de74f&id=fe9e5d931a)

I downloaded the page in addition to 'inspect element' and the code does not use 'display:inline'. As a test, I copy-pasted just the two tables (and their sub table/tr/td(s) and the title and description were no longer horizontally aligned.

My question: is 'display:block' which is defined in CSS h1 selector and this block of code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
        td[class=columnsContainer]{
            display:block !important;
            max-width:600px !important;
            width:100% !important;
```

Are there any additional recommended takeaways from this markup that I can use for another template in my attempt to make two tables (and specifically the tds within) horizontally align? (e.g. use of valign, padding, etc)

Comment: Set all td's css to {vertical-align:top}

Comment: Hey Alexy, thanks for the comment. I created two tables within the 'Table' class and set both <td valign="top"> and that did not solve the issue. Is this a formatting problem only CSS can solve?

Comment: Because valign is not a styling tag. You have to vertical-align:top

Comment: Cleaned up my comments and drafted an HTML newsletter template:
http://us10.campaign-archive1.com/?u=798e118519332dab2c5558919&id=d830900a53&e=4b1543b942

Comment: Alexey, would you have any suggestions for next steps or certain concepts (like fleshing out the tables and adding additional tds) that I am missing?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I have two td classes both of which have a {vertical-align:top} property and they're still not horizontally inline like the example newsletter; why is this?

Comment: For horizontal inline you need to justify the text such as text-align:center or text-align:left; You sure you need horizontally?

Comment: the horizontality would be preferred and it's also a valuable opportunity to learn. All the TD classes have the 'vertical-align:top' and 'text-align:left' properties. 
I noticed the linked BenedictEvan's newsletter  has three nested table &  td elements so I have been duplicating that and setting each <td> class to have a vertical-align:top property